# 12V vs 5V servo

Tags: servo, emc, interference

I am looking to actuate a throttle on an internal combustion engine. I am using a 5V servo driven by an Arduino Mega2560 at the moment. The throttle is very close to the engines alternator and there appears to be a significant amount of noise on the signal. With the throttle held in place by hand and the servo left to run say the sweep program (through 180 degrees and back again) the position does not change smoothly.

My question is if I use a servo of different voltage, say 12V will this be less susceptible to noise?

Comment: When you say "signal", which signal is that?

Comment: The PWM signal going to the servo

Comment: Is the servo shaking heavily and/or exposed to heat? I encountered big problems with servos mounted near/on engines because of that.

Comment: Yes it is exposed to both heat and vibration but when the servo is removed from the throttle and the throttle is fixed in position and the servo 1 meter away from the machine the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look in to a few things.  The signal to a servo varies from 1ms to 2ms for stop to stop operation.  Hence, a 1.5ms signal centers the servo.  This signal comes along every 18ms.  The ignition system generates a high voltage spike every time a plug fires that can easily get into nearby electronics and confuse your servo.  In cars, they use resistive wire and resistor plugs to minimize radio interference.  Many smaller engines use solid copper wire and non-resistive plugs and are far more likely to create interference.  I had a WWII 4 cylinder generator that used fully shielded distributor, spark plug wires and spark plugs for RF suppression.

Keep wires short and away from electrical noise sources if possible.  I like to twist or braid wires together to help cut down on interference.

If you are using a radio control system that works in the sub Ghz range, be aware that metal-on-metal linkages will also cause radio interference.  In model airplanes, all control surface and engine linkages had to be metal to plastic or the metal parts had to be bonded to one another with a short wire.

So far as 5v v.s. 12v?  I doubt it.  The 12v system will most likely have a higher impedance than the 5v system, making it just as susceptible.

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the supply voltage of the servo, that doesn't change the control voltage (the voltage of the PWM signal). A 12V servo still uses the 5V PWM signal from the Arduino. However, a 12V servo might have a bit more heft, which could be helpful.

Try using a shielded cable, and keep the cable as far away from the alternator for as much of its run as possible. If that doesn't help, you could try opto-isolation, a differential signal, or even a fiber optic run between the Arduino and the servo (you'd need a small control board on the servo to convert the optical signal back to electrical).

Edit:

A 12V drive signal *might* help, but this can only be done if the servo can handle a 12V control input. Another thing to try would be put a line driver after the Arduino; a line driver has a lower output impedance and can therefore drive the cable "harder", making it less susceptible to noise. If possible, a differential line driver matched with a differential line receiver might work very well. This assumes you have or can run a differential cable.

Regarding opto-isolation: this would eliminate issues with different grounds, which might be giving you trouble. However, it requires running power along the cable, which might cause even more problems.

Comment: Thanks for that! What about if i changed the 5V PWM signal to a 12V signal with a level converter? I am already using a shielded cable, there is limited possibility on changing the physical cable run. How would opto-isolation help? Would the signals not still have the noise transferred from primary to secondary?

Comment: @Gawnie Tried to answer some of those questions in my edit above.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have removed the servo from the vicinity of the engine and have the arduino controlling the servo running the "sweep" example file (which turns the servo in steps through 180 degrees and then back). When the engine is switched off the servo moves smoothly (removed from the machine, throttle fixed in position by hand). However, when the engine is running and the servo is 1m away from the machine, the servo is irratic, with the angle jumping all over the place. Does this indicate that the signal needs to be decoupled? Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: It might be helpful to put a scope on the PWM signal near the servo end, to see what the nature of the interference is.